# Best way to get the id from an entity we just saved?

Tags: mongoose

I would like to know if there is a way to get the ID (automatically generated in the BDD) of an entity we just saved with mongoose.

Maybe there is a callback or something on the save method, i didn't find anything about it on the documentation, except the error callback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_id` of a newly created document is created on the client, not the server.  So it's actually available before you even call `save`.

```js
var newDoc = new MyModel({name: 'foobar'});
console.log(newDoc._id); // logs the assigned _id
newDoc.save(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc._id);  // also available here; newDoc._id == doc._id
});
```