# Get entity ID before creating new entity in DB

Tags: express, coffeescript, mongoose, entity

I use Nodejs and express, angularJs and coffeScripts, mongodb and mongoose,

I would like to store the ID of a new entity before creating the entity in the DB.

In my angular controller written with coffescripts I have this code

```
$scope.addPlayer = ->
    $http.post '/api/players',
      name: "PlayerName"
```

And from this piece of code I would like to store the id of my new player, I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005312/best-way-to-get-the-id-from-an-entity-we-just-saved) very close to what I need, yet I cannot figure out by myself how to write this for my code, i need to get the player._id to update this player later on ^^

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to make sure your /api/players endpoint returns the newly created entity.

Then, on the client side, simply take the response and you will have access to the _id attribute for future use.

HTH,

Mike